# FuelPHP - Uploaded file permission issue

Tags: upload, permissions, fuelphp

I'm on Ubuntu and I'm using the [FuelPHP Upload Class](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/upload/usage.html), to handle my uploads. Here is my configuration:

```
$config = array(
                    'path' =>"path/to/upload/folder",
                    'auto_rename'   => true,
                    'randomize' => true,
                    'ext_whitelist' => array('webm', 'ogg', 'mp4'),
                    'create_path'   => true,
                    'path_chmod'    => 0777,
                    'file_chmod'    => 0777,
                );
```

Which I give directly to 'Upload' class 'process' static method like this:

```
Upload::process($config);
```

I've set 'file_chmod' to '0777' but when I check the file permission of the uploaded file I don't get a 0777 instead I get a 0644. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the web server user (www-data in my case) not having ownership of the upload directory. Hence the FuelPHP `Upload::process()` method could not automatically change the file permission to 0777. I fixed it using:

```
sudo chown www-data my/upload/folder
```

Hope this would help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

just my 2ct. If you chmod a file, then 0666 would be enough in most cases. because 0777 adds 'execute' permission. But on photos, text files files (everything except executables) you don't need 0777.

So in your setup, as I see it - 0666 will be more than enough.

Have a nice day!

Comment: I agree with on that, the whole reason I wanted the 0777 permission was to check a functionality of my app, I'll certainly not give that permission when my app goes live. Thanks for the heads up!